# syntax to call un-overridden method

Tags: java

I have

```
public class D extends B
{
    public void method() {}
}

public class B
{
    public void method() {}

    public void anotherMethod() { method(); }
}
```

In the above, if you hold an instance of D, say d, d.anotherMethod() results in calling D.method.

Is there a syntax in Java to call B.method() from inside anotherMethod()?

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. The derived class would have to contain a call to `super.method()`.

If `B` wants to prevent subclasses from overriding `method()`, it should declare `method()` as `final`.

Comment: Hmm... thought so, unlike in C++ where you could have done B::method() if I remember the syntax right.

Comment: B doesn't want to prevent subclasses from overriding method(), since there are other methods in B that does want to invoke the overridden method(). Sure there are ways to get around it with multiple methods, but just wondering if I could avoid it.

Comment: There is no direct way as such... a workaround can be is to check the class type and invoke method accordingly but things will become messy...

Comment: Was re-reading the statement "Only the overriding method can invoke the overridden method.", this isn't correct. I can do super.method()  from any of the derived class' method not just from D's method - the overriding method, right?

Comment: wizard@ - Oops, you're right, you certainly can. If I understand what you'd like to do, that doesn't help, however.

Answer (score 0):

You still can call the super method by explicitly using super like this this:

```
public class D extends B{
    public void method() {}
    public void anotherMethod() { super.method(); }
}
```

The only thing that is required is for you to override anotherMethod().

Another way is thinking like this. You want anotherMethod to call B method() so:

```
public class D extends B{
    public void methodInternal() {}
}
public class B{
    public final void method() {
        //...
        methodInternal();
    }
    public void methodInternal() {}
    public void anotherMethod() { method(); }
}
```

Here the user can create his own version of `method()` by overriding `methodInternal()`, but still the behavior of the original `method()` is intact.

Comment: Yes, I am the one developing B, I have no control over D, I don't want to have to have my B.anotherMethod() invoking the overridden method() but my own.

Comment: Then you must prevent subclasses for overriding method() with `final`

Comment: I can't because I do have other methods in B that should invoke the overridden method()

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, but it is sad that my B.method() isn't usable to myself once I allow it to be overridden :( (me, being the developer of B)

Answer (score 0):

You can make `method()` static in `B` and then call it as `B.method()` from the instance methods where it is needed (you may need to rename the static method if you want to use the name for the instance method).

At least that's what I do in similar situations.

Maybe you should also reconsider your design.